# How to install Supabase Cli on Mac? its throwing error

Tags: command-line-interface, supabase

Hi I was starting up with supabase function and I could not find how to install supabase cli on my machine when I'm looked into supabase cli documentation. It says just run:

```
npm install -g supabase
```

But after running this command I checked on my terminal. And supabase was not available.

Does anyone knows how to install supabase cli on a mac successfully?

Answer (score 1):

Supabase cli is available via npm as a dev dependency, to install it you need to use

```
npm i supabase --save-dev
```

https://github.com/supabase/cli

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.

First you need to run this command:

```
yarn add -D supabase
```

> Yes I like yarn

But there is one more step you have to run again.

```
yarn add supabase
```

To make it install correctly.
I do not know what it is happening, but I contacted supabase support and this is what they advised.

Hope it helps

Finally check it with

```
npx supabase --help
```

Answer (score 0):

If Homebrew is already installed on your system, you can run below command:

```
brew install supabase-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by adding `npx` before `supabase`.

```bash
npx supabase init
```

Answer (score 0):

Supabase CLI is also available with Homebrew:

```
brew install supabase/tap/supabase
```

Docs: https://github.com/supabase/cli